# Drag & Drop in Multiple divs

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a Problem with JqueryUI Drag & Drop.
I have a list on the left side where i can drag an object. I want to drag an Objekt in an Container or outside. If its dropped inside it should become a normal object. If its dropped outside it should become a container.
All works fine, but not when i drag the objekt outside. it dont become a container.

Heres the Website:
http://dannyforce.bplaced.de/Intera/droppable/

The containersw are wrapped with the divid= "objekte". The Objekts inside the containers with the divclass= "container".

When i place the objekt in a contaier, this works:

```
$(".container").droppable({
                drop: function( evt, ui ){
                    ui.draggable.find( 'div' )
                        .addClass("objekts")//.unwrap();
                }
             });
```

So i thought, this would work for the objekts:

```
$("#objekte").droppable({
                drop: function( evt, ui ){
                    ui.draggable.find( 'div' )
                        .addClass("container").unwrap()
                }
             });
```

But it dont. It do nothing when i drop it in the "objekte"-div

mfg,

Daniel

Comment: Heres the full source

view-source:http://dannyforce.bplaced.de/Intera/droppable/

Answer (score 1):

Use html5 drag and drop facility:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Comment: This is a suggestion, not an answer to his question.